# how can i do inserting data in sqlserver?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i've write the following code but i did not have any success to inserting data in my DB.
what's your suggestion ?

my database name id syn
in "syn" i have one table named synreplace with 4 columns (Number,word,syn,freq)
which number is primary key.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Word = textBox5.Text;
    string Syn = textBox6.Text;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\bin\Debug\syn.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        textBox4.Text = "Well done!";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        textBox4.Text = "You failed!" + ex.ToString();
    }

    try
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO synreplace (word,syn)" + "Values ('Wgord','Shyn')", myConnection);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + "wow";
        myCommand.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting data into a sqlserverdatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584261/inserting-data-into-a-sqlserverdatabase)

Comment: @SLaks the data just doesnt insert . i have no error actually

Comment: the textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + "wow"; is executed ?

Comment: Is `Number` an identity field? Does `freq` allow nulls? Why don't you close the connection anyway?

Comment: What is the exception or the problem?

Comment: @Akrem yup it execute

Comment: The problemn is that ilia7 is not willing to read documentation or a tutorial. That simple.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy yes Number is an identity field . and freq doesnt allow nulls .

Comment: @TomTom i just read . but i have no time . :(

Comment: @Nacho no exception . just data doesnt insert

Comment: Look if the 'freq' allows Nulls, and the space in the sql command (the Akrem answer)

Comment: @ilia7 StackOverflow is supposed to be a site for professional developers. The questions you ask are schoolboy level and you don't seem to be willing to read basic programming material. It is not reasonable for you to expect professional developers to write your project for you with little or no input from yourself. This is chapter-one stuff in most beginners programming books. Please read a beginners programmers book and get yourself up to student level programmer before asking more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make space between ')' and Value

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO synreplace (word,syn) Values ('Wgord','Shyn')", myConnection);
```

and check if freq accept null

**update**

you create the mdf file always when you run debug, then you erase the old mdf and create the new mdf (in this case you loose your inserted data)

to check if your data is added you can insert your data and take your mdf file and attach it to sqlManagment to check your inserted data

Comment: i tried it but any success :(